# how can I search for my contacts by only providing the words not start from the beginning?

Tags: contacts, search

I am using Android mobile phone. In the Contacts, I find out that it can only search for contacts if I provide the words start from the beginning.

For example, if my friend is called "David". I could not find him if I only put "vid" in the search box.

May I ask how to improve the search algorithm for my mobile phone (I know it is doable for Google Contacts)? Thank you.

Comment: Some manufacturers replace the contacts app with their own. What make of phone do you have?

Comment: I am using wileyfox